# What does this function definition mean?

Tags: c++, c

[This function definition is found here.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) :

```
static void (*resolve_memcpy (void)) (void)
{
    return my_memcpy; // we'll just always select this routine
}
```

I don't understand what it means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

resolve_memcpy is a function taking no arguments and returning a pointer to a function taking no arguments and returning void.

EDIT: Here's a link where you can read more about this kind of syntax: http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html

Comment: So it says in the link :D. I don't understand the syntax though. Can you be more elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

Here's my standard method for reading hairy declarations: start with the leftmost identifier and work your way out, remembering that absent any explicit grouping `()` and `[]` bind before `*`:

```
              resolve_memcpy               -- resolve_memcpy
              resolve_memcpy(void)         --  is a function taking no arguments
             *resolve_memcpy(void)         --  and returning a pointer
            (*resolve_memcpy(void)) (void) --   to a function taking no arguments
       void (*resolve_memcpy(void)) (void) --   and returning void
static void (*resolve_memcpy(void)) (void) -- and is not exported to the linker
```

So the return value of the `resolve_memcpy` function is a pointer to another function:

```
void (*fptr)(void) = resolve_memcpy();
fptr(); // or (*fptr)(), if you want to be explicit
```

If you want to drive your coworkers insane, you could write

```
resolve_memcpy()();
```

which will execute the function whose pointer is returned by `resolve_memcpy`.

Answer (score 2):

One can use [cdecl](http://www.cdecl.org/) to find:

> declare resolve_memcpy as static function (void) returning pointer to function (void) returning void

Answer (score 0):

It basically returns a function pointer, which (presumably) you're supposed to use instead of `memcpy`.

```
// memcpy(...)
resolve_memcpy()(...) // Use this instead.
```